# How should I 'rotate' or 'flatten' this research data? PIVOT, self join or something else?

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm having a really hard time finding any examples that are close to what I'm doing, or I'm simply not understanding the examples I'm finding.

I have a research database that contains a persons responses to multiple questions at different points in time.  'Admin#' below represents which "administration" of the test the data represents.  Or you can think of it as containing which 'time' the test was given, for example, time1, time2, time3

```
RespondentID# Admin# Question1 Question2 Question3 Question4 Question5
            1      1     A         B        C          D         E
            1      2     E         D        C          B         A
            1      3     Q         W        E          R         T
            2      1     Z         X        C          V         B
            2      2     P         O        I          U         Y
            2      3     Y         H        N          U         J
```

What I need to do now is arrange this data so that each set of responses for a particular respondent is in the same row. So we'd take the 5 question fields and turn them into 15 question fields,

```
RespondentID# Admin1Question1 Admin1Question2 Admin1Question3 Admin1Question4 Admin1Question5 Admin2Question1 Admin2Question2 Admin2Question3 Admin2Question4 Admin2Question5 Admin3Question1 Admin3Question2 Admin3Question3 Admin3Question4 Admin3Question5
```

As you can see, every field that begins with Admin1 would correspond to the row in the example above that has a Admin# value of 1.

Please forgive me if I'm not explaining this properly.

To further complicate matters, the maximum number of "administrations" or "times" can increase in the future.  Currently it is 3, but it is possible that the same test could be administered 4, 5 or more times in the future. Whatever solution used for this problem can be static and then updated by hand to account for additional "times" in the future, but it would be awesome if the solution dynamically accounted for an unspecified number of "times".

This data is stored in a MS SQL 2005 database, so tsql is obviously an option, but if a better solution exists in C# or LINQ (the overall project is an asp.net app), I'm open to that as well.  Whatever you think works best! :)

Thanks so much for reading my question!

Comment: How likely is it that the number of *questions* on the test changes?

Comment: It is not very likely, maybe even 'impossible', for the number of questions to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic approach I'm following is to manually pivot using code like:

```
select RespondentID,
    min(case when Admin=1 then Question1 else null end) Admin1_Question1,
    min(case when Admin=2 then Question1 else null end) Admin2_Question1,
    min(case when Admin=3 then Question1 else null end) Admin3_Question1
from tests
group by RespondentID
```

So, using a dynamic t-sql statement we build and execute the query for this as follows:

```
declare @select varchar(max)

select @select = coalesce(@select+',','')+
    'min(case when Admin='+a+' then '+q+' else null end) as [Admin'+a+'_'+q+']'
from (select distinct cast(Adminas varchar(10)) a from tests) p1
    cross join (
    select 'Question1' q union
    select 'Question2' union
    select 'Question3' union
    select 'Question4' union
    select 'Question5'
    ) p2
order by a, q


declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = 'select RespondentID, '+@select+' from tests group by RespondentID'

execute(@sql)
```

It's not the most dynamic t-sql solution available, but it should work!

Comment: Ok, after DAYS of trying out various iterations of the suggestions submitted, I finally went with this one for a number of reasons, not the least of which is that this answer was the easiest for me to understand and also most directly solved my problem. After all, it creates the table structure I need for this data, and allows me to easily execute a dbdatareader against the result set and write those variables out to the data's final destination.  Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

What I'm thinking is to take each record of 5 questions, and normalize Respondent, Admin and Question into a list of individual answers, which you can then group by Respondent.

```
var myResultsList = GetResultsFromDatabase();

var normalizedResults = myResultsList
   .SelectMany(r=>new[]{
      new{Respondent = r.RespondentId, Admin = r.AdminId, Question = 1, Answer= r.Question1},
      new{Respondent = r.RespondentId, Admin = r.AdminId, Question = 2, Answer = r.Question2},
      new{Respondent = r.RespondentId, Admin = r.AdminId, Question = 3, Answer = r.Question3},
      new{Respondent = r.RespondentId, Admin = r.AdminId, Question = 4, Answer = r.Question4},
      new{Respondent = r.RespondentId, Admin = r.AdminId, Question = 5, Answer = r.Question5},
   };

//finding a single answer, by respondent, admin and question:
normalizedList.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Respondent == 1 && x.Admin == 2 && x.Question == 1);
```

Now you have a list of an anonymous type with Respondent, Admin, Question and Answer fields. You can now group these elements by Respondent, and produce a Lookup (basically a Dictionary of Lists) keyed by Respondent ID:

```
var groupedResults = normalizedResults.GroupBy(r=>r.RespondentID);

//Get all records for Respondent # 1, ordered by Admin and Question:
var oneRespondentsResults = normalizedResults[1].OrderBy(x=>x.Admin).ThenBy(x=>x.Question);
```

If you really wanted to get fancy, you could set them up in a nested Dictionary structure and refer to the answers by a unique combination of key fields:

```
var nestedDictionary = normalizedResults
    .ToDictionary(x=>x.Respondent,
        x=>nestedDictionary.Where(x2=>x2.Respondent == x.Respondent)
            .ToDictionary(x2=>x2.Admin,
                x2=>nestedDictionary.Where(x3=>x3.Respondent == x2.Respondent && x3.Admin == x2.Admin)
                    .ToDictionary(x3=>x3.Question, x3=>x3.Answer)));

//All that mess makes getting to a single value pretty easy:
var answer = nestedDictionary[1][2][1]; //Respondent 1, Admin 2, Question 1
```

If these results need to be used outside the function that creates them, set up a struct or simple class to take the place of the anonymous type (you can still use the inferred array initializer), or use the nested Dictionary (which will be keyed or valued in the primitive types contained in the anonymous type).

Answer (score 2):

After reading @KeithS's answer, I thought of the following approach using PIVOT and UNPIVOT:

Use UNPIVOT to normalize the original data to `RepsondentID, FullQuestionID, Answer`:

```
select RespondentID,
       [FullQuestionID] = 'Admin'+cast(admin as varchar)+'_'+question,
       Answer
from (
       select RespondentID, Admin, Question1, Question2, Question3, Question4, Question5
       from tests
     ) t UNPIVOT (
       answer for question in (Question1, Question2, Question3, Question4, Question5)
     ) up
```

Then use PIVOT to un-normalize the data into your desired RespondentID list:

```
;with data as (
  --unpivot code
)
select RespondentID, [Admin1_Question1], [Admin2_Question1], [Admin3_Question1]
from data
  PIVOT (min(Answer) for FullQuestionID in
     ([Admin1_Question1], [Admin2_Question1], [Admin3_Question1])
  ) p
```

Then finally, you can use dynamic t-sql to build the list of all Admin/Question combinations.  With everything together it looks like the following:

```
declare @list varchar(max)
select @list = coalesce(@list+',','')+'[Admin'+a+'_'+q+']'
from (select distinct cast(admin as varchar) a from tests) p1
    cross join (
        select 'Question1' q union
        select 'Question2' union
        select 'Question3' union
        select 'Question4' union
        select 'Question5'
    ) p2
order by a, q

declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql =
';with data as (
    select RespondentID, [FullQuestionID]=''Admin''+cast(Admin as varchar)+''_''+question, Answer
    from (
        select respondentID, Admin, Question1, Question2, Question3, Question4, Question5
        from tests
        ) p
    UNPIVOT
        (answer for question in
            (Question1, Question2, Question3, Question4, Question5)
        ) as unPvt
)
select respondentID, '+@list+'
from data d
    PIVOT (min(answer) for FullQuestionID in
        ('+@list+')
    ) p'

exec(@sql)
```